# Where does test payload go using Android Studio with Gradle?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am running unit test and would like to test json deserialization, so I put a .json file in the same package as my unit test class, I was able to load it like the following in eclipse before I converted my project to the gradle structure but I could no longer load the file now with android studio + gradle

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("testdata.json");
```

Please advice where should the test payload go and how I should reference the file.